# Unable to use AAC/AptX codec for bluetooth audio on macOS

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, aac

When accessing the Bluetooth Explorer and setting the "Enable AAC" and "Force use AptX" to true, all the bluetooth audio devices still use the SBC codec.

When pressing "Reset audio defaults" - bluetooth explorer crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
```

Tried to use these terminal commands, but still no luck.

```
sudo defaults write bluetoothaudiod "Enable AptX codec" -bool true
sudo defaults write bluetoothaudiod "Enable AAC codec" -bool true
```

I'm on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014), macOS Catalina 10.15.1 
I feel like it's the first time I have a problem that I can't find any info on in google.

Please help! :p

Comment: I have exactly same error when trying to open Bluetooth Explorer -> Tools -> Audio Options.

Comment: I don't really know where to go with this :p

Comment: Same here. 
Somebody has reinstalled whole OS and it helped, but that's not acceptable for me 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250945131

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with bluetooth exlplore so i tried disabled the aptx and enabled the AAC via terminal and it works. now my active coded is AAC

```
sudo defaults write bluetoothaudiod "Enable AptX codec" -bool false
sudo defaults write bluetoothaudiod "Enable AAC codec" -bool true
```